# JavaScript game with a lagging Mobile Button Controls

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I've created a simple keyboard controlled JavaScript game (extra task from front-end bootcamp I finished recently). A few days ago I decided to add controls for mobile devices, and while keyboard control works well (response from the game is instantaneous), mobile controls 'suffer' from some kind of lag.

Main game controlling JS code:

```js
var Zombie = require('./zombie.js');
var Brain = require('./brain.js');
var Trap = require('./trap.js');


function Game() {
  this.board = document.querySelectorAll('#board div');
  this.zombie = new Zombie();
  this.brain = new Brain();
  this.trap = new Trap();
  this.trap2 = new Trap();
  this.trap3 = new Trap();
  this.trap4 = new Trap();
  this.trap5 = new Trap();
  this.score = 0;
  this.speed = 320;
  this.index = function(x, y) {
    return x + (y * 10);
  }

  this.showZombie = function() {
    this.board[this.index(this.zombie.x, this.zombie.y)].classList.add('zombie');
  }

  this.hideVisibleZombie = function() {
    document.querySelector('.zombie').classList.remove('zombie');
  }

  this.showBrain = function() {
    this.board[this.index(this.brain.x, this.brain.y)].classList.add('brain');

    if(!(this.brain.x === this.trap.x && this.brain.y === this.trap.y)) {
      this.board[this.index(this.trap.x, this.trap.y)].classList.add('trap');
    }

    if(!(this.brain.x === this.trap2.x && this.brain.y === this.trap2.y)) {
      this.board[this.index(this.trap2.x, this.trap2.y)].classList.add('trap');
    }

    if(!(this.brain.x === this.trap3.x && this.brain.y === this.trap3.y)) {
      this.board[this.index(this.trap3.x, this.trap3.y)].classList.add('trap');
    }

    if(!(this.brain.x === this.trap4.x && this.brain.y === this.trap4.y)) {
      this.board[this.index(this.trap4.x, this.trap4.y)].classList.add('trap');
    }

    if(!(this.brain.x === this.trap5.x && this.brain.y === this.trap5.y)) {
      this.board[this.index(this.trap5.x, this.trap5.y)].classList.add('trap');
    }


  }

  this.moveZombie = function() {

    this.hideVisibleZombie();
    if (this.zombie.direction === "right") {
      this.zombie.x += 1;
    } else if (this.zombie.direction === "left") {
      this.zombie.x -= 1;
    } else if (this.zombie.direction === "up") {
      this.zombie.y -= 1;
    } else if (this.zombie.direction === "down") {
      this.zombie.y += 1;
    }

    if (!(this.gameOver())) {
      this.showZombie();
      this.checkBrainCollision();
    }
  }

  this.turnZombie = function(event) {


    switch (event.which /*|| e.which*/) {
      case 37:
        this.zombie.direction = 'left';
        break;
      case 38:
        this.zombie.direction = 'up';
        break;
      case 39:
        this.zombie.direction = 'right';
        break;
      case 40:
        this.zombie.direction = 'down';
        break;
    }
   }

   this.turnMobileZombie = function(event) {
     switch (true) {
       case event.currentTarget.classList.contains('up'):
         this.zombie.direction = 'up';
         break;
       case event.currentTarget.classList.contains('down'):
         this.zombie.direction = 'down';
         break;
       case event.currentTarget.classList.contains('left'):
         this.zombie.direction = 'left';
         break;
       case event.currentTarget.classList.contains('right'):
         this.zombie.direction = 'right';
         break;
     }
    }


  this.checkBrainCollision = function() {

    if (this.zombie.x === this.brain.x && this.zombie.y === this.brain.y) {
      document.querySelector('.brain').classList.remove('brain');
      document.querySelectorAll('.trap').forEach(e => e.classList.remove('trap'));
      document.querySelector('.eat').play();
      this.score++
      document.querySelector('#score strong').innerText = this.score;
      this.increaseSpeed();
      this.brain = new Brain();
      this.trap = new Trap();
      this.trap2 = new Trap();
      this.trap3 = new Trap();
      this.trap4 = new Trap();
      this.trap5 = new Trap();
      this.showBrain();
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }


  this.gameOver = function() {
    if (
      (this.zombie.x < 0 || this.zombie.x > 9 || this.zombie.y < 0 || this.zombie.y > 9) ||
      ((this.zombie.x === this.trap.x && this.zombie.y === this.trap.y) && (this.brain.x !== this.trap.x || this.brain.y !== this.trap.y)) ||
      ((this.zombie.x === this.trap2.x && this.zombie.y === this.trap2.y) && (this.brain.x !== this.trap2.x || this.brain.y !== this.trap2.y)) ||
      ((this.zombie.x === this.trap3.x && this.zombie.y === this.trap3.y) && (this.brain.x !== this.trap3.x || this.brain.y !== this.trap3.y)) ||
      ((this.zombie.x === this.trap4.x && this.zombie.y === this.trap4.y) && (this.brain.x !== this.trap4.x || this.brain.y !== this.trap4.y)) ||
      ((this.zombie.x === this.trap5.x && this.zombie.y === this.trap5.y) && (this.brain.x !== this.trap5.x || this.brain.y !== this.trap5.y))
    ) {
      document.querySelector('.dead').play();
      clearInterval(this.idSetInterval);
      document.querySelector('.brain').classList.remove('brain');
      document.querySelectorAll('.trap').forEach(e => e.classList.remove('trap'));
      document.querySelector('#over').classList.remove('invisible');
      document.querySelector('#over').classList.remove('none');
      document.querySelector('p span').innerText = this.score;
      return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
  }
  var self = this;

  document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    self.turnZombie(event);
  });

  document.querySelectorAll('.mobile-controller div').forEach((e,i) => {
    if(e.classList.contains('up') || e.classList.contains('down') || e.classList.contains('left') || e.classList.contains('right')) {
      e.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        self.turnMobileZombie(event);
      })
    };
  })

  // $(document).on('click', '.mobile-controller div', function(e) {
  //    var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
  //    if ($(this).hasClass('left')) {
  //       e.which = 37;
  //       self.turnZombie(e);
  //    }
  //    else if ($(this).hasClass('up')) {
  //       e.which = 38;
  //       self.turnZombie(e);
  //    }
  //    else if ($(this).hasClass('right')) {
  //        e.which = 39;
  //        self.turnZombie(e);
  //    }
  //    else if ($(this).hasClass('down')) {
  //       e.which = 40;
  //       self.turnZombie(e);
  //    }
  //    $(document).trigger(e);
  //    });

  this.startGame = function() {
      this.idSetInterval = setInterval(function() {
        self.moveZombie()
      }, this.speed);
  }

  this.increaseSpeed = function () {
            this.speed -= 5;
            clearInterval(this.idSetInterval);
            this.idSetInterval = setInterval(function() {
              self.moveZombie()
            }, this.speed);
    };


}

module.exports = Game;
```

Preview of the game here: [link](https://m-zaremba.github.io/Zombie-Game/)

Link to GitHub repo here: [link](https://github.com/m-zaremba/Zombie-Game)

As You can see, I've tried a jQuery solution - controls work, but still with the same lag. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Mouse click events wait until you've lifted your finger before firing.  With a game you want instant reactions, so change click to mousedown... `e.addEventListener('mousedown'`

Comment: @Archer: Thanks for Your reply. 'mousedown' wasn't a solution to my problem, but thanks to Your idea I used 'touchstart' and now the mobile controller works great.

Comment: Glad it at least pointed you in the right direction.  Have fun :)

Comment: Nice game :-). When played on a Desktop PC, using the UP and DOWN keys causes a bit of scrolling as the content of the page is higher than the viewport. Either get rid of the scrollbars (`body { overflow-y: hidden; }`) or add some JS to prevent scrolling.

Comment: Thanks, Sascha :) I used 'overflow-y: hidden', as You advised :)